# PostgreSQL and Kafka Connect integration issue

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am testing JDBC Sink connector to dump records from Kafka to PostgreSQL. Here is the Connector config:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink-postgresql-1",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "role",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user=&password=",
        "auto.create": "false",                                                   
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "mode":"incrementing",
        "table.name.format":"role",
        "pk.mode":"record_value",
        "pk.fields":"role_id"
    }
}
```

When I run the connector, I am getting below exception:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 INSERT INTO "role" ("role_id","role_name") VALUES (123,'admin') ON CONFLICT ("role_id") DO UPDATE SET "role_name"=EXCLUDED."role_name" was aborted.  
   Call getNextException to see the cause.
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2778))
```

Any pointers as to what am I missing here? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the name of your table and schema are correct?

Comment: @Giorgos Myrianthous - Thank you for quick response. Name of the table and topic is role. Schema name is public and database name is postgres.

Comment: Can you try to run INSERT INTO "role" ("role_id","role_name") VALUES (123,'admin') ON CONFLICT ("role_id") DO UPDATE SET "role_name"=EXCLUDED."role_name" on your database and see what happens?

Comment: Also, what Kafka version are you running?

Comment: That was the first thing I did after noticing the issue and it worked fine without any issues. I am running confluent Kafka 4.0.0

Comment: Can you include "batch.size": "0" in your sink connector configuration? Then stop and re-run your connector. This won't solve your issue but it might give a more detailed error.

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosMyrianthous on pointing this out. I was able to find the root cause. I've answered the question in the hopes that someone would be able to find it useful some day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was with the table. This is how I created table at first:

```
CREATE TABLE role(
 role_id int PRIMARY KEY,
 role_name VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

The test data in topic looked like this:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic role --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081/  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myRecord","fields": [{"name": "role_id","type": "int"},{"name": "role_name","type": "string"}]}' --key-serializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer --value-serializer io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer --property print.key=true
{"role_id":122, "role_name":"admin"}
{"role_id":123, "role_name":"admin"}
{"role_id":124, "role_name":"admin"}
{"role_id":125, "role_name":"admin"}
{"role_id":126, "role_name":"admin"}
```

So, when my test data had the same value for role_name field again and again, it violated the unique constraint and hence the error.

**What all I did?**

I dropped the table.

Created a new table without the unique key constraint and the above data was pushed to PostgreSQL without issues.